# Highcharts in R to enable different colours for each series for xrange type plots with the same y value?

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts

I would like to have different colours for different series for 'xrange' type plots. This doesn't work when there are multiple series on the same line (same y value). Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the example code block. I would like all three series to have different colours.

```
# Create a data frame with three series
df <- data.frame(start = c(-10, -20, -30), end = c(10, 20, 30), y = rep(1, 3))

# Create a color vector with three colors
colors <- c("#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF")

highchart() %>%
  hc_plotOptions(xrange = list(grouping = FALSE, colorByPoint = TRUE), 
                 enableMouseTracking = TRUE, 
                 column = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
  hc_add_series(df[1, ], "xrange", color = colors[1], hcaes(x = start, x2 = end, y = y), name = "Series 1") %>%
  hc_add_series(df[2, ], "xrange", color = colors[2], hcaes(x = start, x2 = end, y = y), name = "Series 2") %>%
  hc_add_series(df[3, ], "xrange", color = colors[3], hcaes(x = start, x2 = end, y = y), name = "Series 3") %>%
  hc_xAxis(min = -100, max = 100, title = FALSE, plotLines = list(list(value = 0)))
```

I would ideally have something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
# Create a data frame with three series
df <- data.frame(start = c(-10, -0, 20), end = c(0, 20, 30), y = rep(1, 3))

# Create a color vector with three colors
colors <- c("#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF")

highchart() %>%
  hc_plotOptions(xrange = list(grouping = FALSE, colorByPoint = FALSE), 
                 enableMouseTracking = TRUE, 
                 column = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
  hc_add_series(df[1, ], "xrange", color = colors[1], hcaes(x = start, x2 = end, y = y), name = "Series 1") %>%
  hc_add_series(df[2, ], "xrange", color = colors[2], hcaes(x = start, x2 = end, y = y), name = "Series 2") %>%
  hc_add_series(df[3, ], "xrange", color = colors[3], hcaes(x = start, x2 = end, y = y), name = "Series 3") %>%
  hc_xAxis(min = -100, max = 100, title = FALSE, plotLines = list(list(value = 0)))
```

Comment: Omgosh yes! Thank you SO much. I've been trying this for hours and I finally got it!

Answer (score 0):

To have different colors for different series in an 'xrange' type plot in Highcharts R, you can set the color parameter in the hc_add_series() function for each series. In this example, each series is shifted by one unit in the y-axis, so they are not on the same line. The color parameter is set to a different color for each series. Let me know if it helped in your case!

```
library(highcharter)

# Create a data frame with three series
df <- data.frame(start = c(-10, -20, -30), end = c(10, 20, 30), y = rep(1, 3))

# Create a color vector with three colors
colors <- c("#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF")

highchart() %>%
  hc_plotOptions(xrange = list(grouping = FALSE, colorByPoint = TRUE), 
                 enableMouseTracking = TRUE, 
                 column = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
  hc_add_series(df[1, ], "xrange", color = colors[1], hcaes(x = start, x2 = end, y = y), name = "Series 1") %>%
  hc_add_series(df[2, ], "xrange", color = colors[2], hcaes(x = start, x2 = end, y = y + 1), name = "Series 2") %>%
  hc_add_series(df[3, ], "xrange", color = colors[3], hcaes(x = start, x2 = end, y = y + 2), name = "Series 3") %>%
  hc_xAxis(min = -100, max = 100, title = FALSE, plotLines = list(list(value = 0)))
```

Comment: Hi I would have to plot them in a same line - is there any way I could do that?